# Sharing variable between ISR and process

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, interrupt, beagleboard

I'm interested in implementing an ISR in a Single Board Computer(Pi, Beagle Board, etc) which runs Linux in C.

I'm trying to figure out how a hardware driven ISR can share information to a running process.

For bare metal applications you can use a shared memory section between the ISR and other threads running but I don't understand how this is done in Linux.

Comment: KISS (Keep It Stupid Simple) - why not just set a global flag/variable that can be set/unset. Generally you want to declare the global as `volatile` (e.g. `volatile uint16_t samples;`). You also have the option of accessing the value from other source files by declaring the same variable as `extern` in whatever other source you need access to it in. This works regardless of platform. I've used in with the Pi, Pico, TI boards, etc.. You really need to post a MCVE of what you are doing -- if you are using separate threads. you will need pthreads and appropriate mutexes to prevent races.

Comment: Are you writing a Linux kernel module? If so, then you should state that. If not, then you are not writing an ISR, and you should ask a different question.

Comment: Yes, let's suppose I am writing a Linux kernel module.